# Struts 2 s:if with getText

Tags: jsp, if-statement, struts2, internationalization

I want to see if a message key is presented in the message bundles. So I tried below but none of them worked:

```
<s:if test=" getText('site.message') == 'site.message'">
<s:if test=" getText('site.message').equals('site.message')">
<s:if test=" %{getText('site.message').equals('site.message')}">
```

But this workaround works fine:

```
<s:text name="site.message" var="test"/>
<s:if test=" #test=='site.message'">
   Please consider: <s:text name="site.message"/>
</s:if>
```

So is it possible to omit the #test variable and do all works in `s:if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you will use body of the [`<s:text>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/text-tag.html) for your default message instead of body of the `<s:if>` tag. From docs page

> If the named message is not found in a property file, then **the body of the tag will be used as default message**. If no body is used, then the stack will be searched, and if a value is returned, it will written to the output. If no value is found on the stack, the key of the message will be written out. Then you could use another key to set the default message.

The equivalent code

```
<s:text name="site.message"><s:text name="error.message"/></s:text>
```

Also consider default value of the [`getText(String aTextName, String defaultValue)`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#getText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

> Gets a message based on a key, or, if the message is not found, a supplied default value is returned.

Then you can use

```
<s:if test="getText('site.message','') != ''">
   Please consider: <s:text name="site.message"/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
   <s:text name="error.message"/>
</s:else>
```

or check the key with [`hasKey(String key)`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html#hasKey-java.lang.String-)

> Checks if a message key exists.

```
<s:if test="hasKey('site.message')">
   Please consider: <s:text name="site.message"/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
   <s:text name="error.message"/>
</s:else>
```

Comment: I get this warning `The default value expression 'Please consider: site.message' was evaluated and did not match a property.  The literal value 'Please consider: site.message' will be used.` and the page shows `Please consider: site.message` . I am using struts `2.3.24.1`

Comment: The OGNL should work, I don't know what is not working to you.

Comment: The s:text will evaluate its body as OGNL so the syntax must be `<s:text name="site.message">'please consider ' + getText("site.message")</s:text>`.  But it did not help as if the key is not present the result will be `please consider: site.message`. The `hasKey` works fine and the syntax match exactly what I need :) Thanks